# How to iterate over array in batch for key=value item

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, batch-file

I have an array defined as `LIST=(a b c d e)`. The `a, b, c, d, e` are set as system variables, eg. `a=AAA, b=BBB`, etc.

In a batch script, I would like to do a for loop looking like:

```
for %%i in %LIST% do echo %%i=%%%i% (unfortunately, this doesn't work)
```

What I want to achieve is that `%%i (a) = %%%i% (%a%)`, which will be resolved as system variable, thus instead of showing `%a%`, it'll be resolved as `a=AAA`.

Do you have any idea how to do it in a batch script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for %%i in %LIST% do CALL echo %%i=%%%%i%%
```

should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is the same answer of Lorenzo Donati, but in a slightly simpler way...

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set LIST=(a b c d e)
set a=value of A
set b=value of B
set c=value of C
set d=value of D
set e=value of E

for %%G in %LIST% do echo %%G = !%%G!
```

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't very clear what you wanted to do. Try and see if this solves your problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set LIST=(a b c d e)
set a=value of A
set b=value of B
set c=value of C
set d=value of D
set e=value of E

:: deletes the parentheses from LIST
set _list=%LIST:~1,-1%
for  %%G in (%_list%) do (
    set  _name=%%G
    set  _value=!%%G!
    echo !_name! = !_value!
)
```

the script prints the name and the corresponding value of all the environment variables whose names are listed in the variable `LIST`.